# Switch Tabs in SwiftUI on selective NavigationLink/NavigationDestination

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

I have a List of UI Components with NavigationLink. and .navigationDestination modifier. When NavigationLink is tapped, I want to open navigationDestination view only in some of the cases. in other cases my main Tab Bar should switch current selected index.

Following is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
struct SearchView: View {
    
    @Binding var selectedTabIndex: Int
    @State private var searchText: String = ""
    @StateObject var viewModel: SearchViewModel = SearchViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    if viewModel.users.count == 0 {
                        Text("No users found.").font(.headline)
                    } else {
                        ForEach(viewModel.users) { user in
                            NavigationLink(value: user) {
                                UserCell(user: user)
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.top, 8)
                .searchable(text: $searchText, prompt: "Search...")
            }
            .navigationTitle("Explore")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .navigationDestination(for: User.self) { user in
                if !user.shouldSwitchTab {
                    UserProfileView(user: user).navigationBarBackButtonHidden()
                } else { self.selectedTabIndex = 4 }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SearchView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SearchView(selectedTabIndex: .constant(1))
    }
}
```

Above code is giving me error because in `.navigationDestination(for: User.self)` modifier it is expecting a view, instead of tab switching code.

I have tried adding a tap gesture modifier on my navigation link but in that case `.navigationDestination(for: User.self)` stops working.

Below is my code :

```
    ForEach(viewModel.users) { user in
        NavigationLink(value: user) {
            UserCell(user: user)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .onTapGesture {
                    if user.shouldSwitchTab {
                        self.selectedTabIndex = 4
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

How can I achieve selective navigation destination ?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a navigationPath to your view model and listen to it in your navigation stack :

```
class SearchViewModel {
    @Published var path: NavigationPath = .init()
}
```

The you can add a if statement on tap gesture of your cell, and if the statement is true you trigger the navigation by appending you User to the navigation path (make it Hashable).

You finally won't have to deal with the navigationDestination condition you added but just the wanted destination if the condition has been met before.

```
NavigationStack(path: $viewModel.path) { // here you listen to the change
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                if viewModel.users.count == 0 {
                    Text("No users found.").font(.headline)
                } else {
                    ForEach(viewModel.users) { user in
                        UserCell(user: user)
                           .foregroundColor(.black)
                           .onTapGesture {
                            // Here you add your check instead of in the navigationDestination modifier that requires a view
                               if user.shouldSwitchTab {
                                   viewModel.path.append(user)
                               } else {
                                   self.selectedTabIndex = 4
                               }
                           }
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(.top, 8)
            .searchable(text: $searchText, prompt: "Search...")
        }
        .navigationTitle("Explore")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .navigationDestination(for: User.self) { user in
            UserProfileView(user: user)
.navigationBarBackButtonHidden()
        }
    }
```